Replacing values in a raster using a mask in Python
I have a tiff-file with three color bands that I want to mask in Python using a shapefile, but when I use the normal masking method with rasterio, the data points under the mask are replaced with (0,0,0). The issue is that I have other data points in the raster that are (0,0,0) that I do not want to confuse with the masked data. Is there a way to replace either the (0,0,0) data with other values or to get the masked data to give other values than (0,0,0)? My code looks like this:
in_rst = 'some_file.tiff'
in_shp = 'some_other_file.shp'

Vector = gpd.read_file(inshp)

with rasterio.open(in_rst) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src,Vector.geometry,crop=True)
    out_meta=src.meta.copy()

out_meta.update({
    "driver":"Gtiff",
    "height":out_image.shape[1], # height starts with shape[1]
    "width":out_image.shape[2], # width starts with shape[2]
    "transform":out_transform
    })
          
with rasterio.open(in_rst,'w',**out_meta) as dst:
    dst.write(out_image)


Have you trued setting nodata=255. mask(src,Vector.geometry,crop=True,nodata=255)
